# Using a variable as a dynamic property name

Tags: c#

I have this, which works fine:

```
private void BindFilter(DropDownList ddl, IEnumerable<dynamic> items)
{
    ddl.Items.Clear();
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        ddl.Items.Add(item.bodystyle.ToString());
    }
}
```

I know bodystyle is a property on item.

Is it possible though to do this by passing the string as a variable, like this:

```
private void BindFilter(DropDownList ddl, string field, IEnumerable<dynamic> items)
{
    ddl.Items.Clear();
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
         ddl.Items.Add(item.{field}.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that by using reflection:

```
private void BindFilter(DropDownList ddl, string field, IEnumerable<dynamic> items)
{
    ddl.Items.Clear();
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var propertyInfo = item.GetType().GetProperty(field);
        var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(item, null);
        ddl.Items.Add(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: This line - var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(item, null); fails with RuntimeBinderException - Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without using reflection:

```
private void BindFilter(DropDownList ddl, Func<dynamic, string> getStringAction, IEnumerable<dynamic> items)
    {
        ddl.Items.Clear();
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            ddl.Items.Add(getStringAction(item));
        }
    }
```

You call it like so:

```
BindFilter(ddl, item => item.Field.ToString(), items);
```